# How do I assign mutiple integers to another integer?

Tags: c++

This is the real code now if I put in the number 1009 I want the output number to be 7687, now that's not the problem. In the last cout statement when I put in encryptnum I want it to output 7687 so I dont have to put cout << first << second << third << fourth;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
    int fourth;
    int encryptnum;

    cout << " Enter a four digit number to encrypt ";
    cin >> num;

    first = num % 100 / 10;
    second = num % 10;
    third = num % 10000 / 1000;
    fourth = num % 1000 / 100;

    first = (first + 7) % 10;
    second = (second + 7) % 10;
    third = (third + 7) % 10;
    fourth = (fourth + 7) % 10;

    encryptnum = //I want to make encryptnum print out first, second, third, and fourth

    cout << " Encrypted Number " << encryptnum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575840/how-to-assign-multiple-variables-to-another-variable-in-c) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575478/how-to-assign-multiple-variables-to-another-variable-c).

Comment: @chris Thanks for the links, especially for the 2nd, I downvoted it instantly as I've got to see the "Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" paragraph.

Comment: Give us some expected input and output so that we can actually help you instead of guessing.

Comment: you want to assign 4 numbers in `all`?

Comment: oh sorry expected output would be if I put in the numbers 1 2 3 and 4 and i add the line cout << all; then i would want 1234

Comment: @g-makulik It does, it's just that OP has phrased his question **very poorly.**

Comment: @JordanWard Have you heard about [place values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)? Can you multiply? Cool, your problem's now solved.

Comment: @H2CO3 That will only work if the input is single digits only.

Comment: I know my question is worded badly I'm not sure how to ask it. @chris it is kind of the same but I have my code like I want it just for where it says encryptnum I want to have it be cout << " Encrypted Number " << encryptnum; and expected output I want would be 1234 if I put in the numbers 1 2 3 4 without the calculations obvioiusly

Comment: @Angew Why so? Can't one multiply by 100, 1000, 10000 in C++?

Comment: @JordanWard I'm sorry, this is not how stack overflow works. You can't just assign us tasks and reopen a question when you don't get an answer. Think for yourself first. Only ask when you have a concrete question.

Comment: @H2CO3, More like when they enter `23452343 67892343 12323434 32454644`. That's not going to fit very well.

Comment: @chris then `std::stringstream`, ***if and only if*** this is not a math problem.

Comment: @H2CO3, Fair enough. I didn't really consider the possible reasoning behind this problem.

Comment: Okay I edited my question it should be easier to understand now please help.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment (which you should really incorporate into the question to make your objective more clear), this should help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int first, second, third, fourth;
    int all;

    std::cout << " Enter four numbers ";
    std::cin >> first >> second >> third >> fourth;
    std::stringstream s;
    s << first << second << third << fourth; //insert the four numbers right after each other
    s >> all;  //read them as one number

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least with this, you can check for an error if it doesn't fit into the variable. With something like this, that's pretty important.